# How to dynamically change Themes and _Layout in ASP.Net MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4, themes

I want to be able to change the _Layout.cshtml view based on a setting in my database.
I understand that it is probably done in the _ViewStart.cshml view.

I am using EF 4.2 and want to adapt a solution that will not break any design pattern.

**Not sure how to go about doing this in MVC.**

In web forms, I could easily do this in the code-behind for the masterpage.

I am doing something like this in my base controller:

```
public abstract class BaseController : Controller
{
    private IUserRepository _userRepository;


    protected BaseController()
        : this(
            new UserRepository())
    {
    }


    public BaseController(IUserRepository userRepository)
    {
        _userRepository = userRepository;
    }
```

I have looked at FunnelWeb source as well but I am not quite getting how they are injecting things..

Comment: Pass it through ViewBag. Add this ViewStart, ViewContext.Controller.ViewBag.Layout.

Comment: for themes you can look at this live demo: http://prodinner.aspnetawesome.com and download here http://prodinner.codeplex.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Old Question but for anyone coming across this question here is a nice solution using Action Filters Attributes

```
public class LoadUserLayoutAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly string _layoutName;
    public LoadUserLayoutAttribute()
    {
        _layoutName = MethodToGetLayoutNameFromDB();
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
        var result = filterContext.Result as ViewResult;
        if (result != null)
        {
            result.MasterName = _layoutName; 
        }
    }
}
```

and then, you can add an attribute to your base controller (or action) with this custom attribute:

```
    [LoadUserLayout]
    public abstract class BaseController : Controller
    {
       ...
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Add this code to in the RegisterBundles method of the BundleConfig class.  Note that I am creating a separate bundle for each css so that I don't render each css to the client.  I can pick which bundle I want to render in the HEAD section of the shared _Layout.cshtml view.

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/Ceruleancss").Include(
    "~/Content/bootstrapCerulean.min.css",
        "~/Content/site.css"));

bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/defaultcss").Include(
              "~/Content/bootstrap.min.css",
              "~/Content/site.css"));
```

Then put some logic in the shared_Layout.cshtml to render the appropriate bundle.  Since this layout view fires for every page, this is a good place to put it.

I think this approach could be used for branding if you support multiple corps for your app.  It could also be used to provide a custom style by user I suppose.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - Contoso University</title>

@{

    if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name == "MARK")
    {
        @Styles.Render("~/Content/defaultcss");
    }
    else
    {
        @Styles.Render("~/Content/Ceruleancss");
    }

}
```

Comment: That is a nice answer, however i would prefer to put the logic in some class instead of a view.